# getjson on appending <li> image dosent show up how ever url is appending properly

Tags: jquery, wordpress, getjson

i am appending my wordpress post data via jquery. `<li>` appends properly text shown up even in `<img src="">` url is also appending but image is not showing, however image show on windows re-sizing. i am not able to figure out problem any solution or tricks is good considerable

here is my jquery code :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var url2 = location.hostname;
var count= 0;

$('#client-list').click(function(){ 
$('#loading').show();
$.getJSON('http://'+url2+'/?json=get_category_posts&slug=blog',function(data) {

    $('#appended').append('<li class="refresh"><aside class="just-text"><a><div style="color: #000000;"><img src="'+data.posts[count].attachments[0].url+'" style="width:100%"></div><div class="on-hover"></div></a></aside></li>');
    $('#appended').append('<li class="refresh"><aside class="just-text"><div style="color: #000000; "><div class="textContainer"><text><div id="subHeading" style="color:black;height:1.2em!important;font-size:1.4em!important">'+data.posts[count].date+'</div><div id="subHeading2"><a href="<?= get_permalink();?>">'+data.posts[count].title+'</a></div></text></div></div><div class="on-hover"></div></a></aside></li>');
    count++;

    $('#appended').append('<li class="refresh"><aside class="just-text"><a><div style="color: #000000;"><img src="'+data.posts[count].attachments[0].url+'" style="width:100%"></div><div class="on-hover"></div></a></aside></li>');
    $('#appended').append('<li class="refresh"><aside class="just-text"><div style="color: #000000; "><div class="textContainer"><text><div id="subHeading" style="color:black;height:1.2em!important;font-size:1.4em!important">'+data.posts[count].date+'</div><div id="subHeading2"><a href="<?= get_permalink();?>">'+data.posts[count].title+'</a></div></text></div></div><div class="on-hover"></div></a></aside></li>');
    count++;
})
.done(function( json ) {
       //$('#loading').hide();
});

   });
});
```

working code : [myworkingsite](http://glim.webdesk.com.pk/blog/) 
click on more at bottom

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that wordpress has some default javascript events binded to window.onresize and also uses javascript to calculate the height of each image. I think the most handy way to fix this is to trigger the `resize` event programmatically:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var url2 = location.hostname;
var count= 0;

$('#client-list').click(function(){ 
$('#loading').show();
$.getJSON('http://'+url2+'/?json=get_category_posts&slug=blog',function(data) {

    $('#appended').append('<li class="refresh"><aside class="just-text"><a><div style="color: #000000;"><img src="'+data.posts[count].attachments[0].url+'" style="width:100%"></div><div class="on-hover"></div></a></aside></li>');
    $('#appended').append('<li class="refresh"><aside class="just-text"><div style="color: #000000; "><div class="textContainer"><text><div id="subHeading" style="color:black;height:1.2em!important;font-size:1.4em!important">'+data.posts[count].date+'</div><div id="subHeading2"><a href="<?= get_permalink();?>">'+data.posts[count].title+'</a></div></text></div></div><div class="on-hover"></div></a></aside></li>');
    count++;

    $('#appended').append('<li class="refresh"><aside class="just-text"><a><div style="color: #000000;"><img src="'+data.posts[count].attachments[0].url+'" style="width:100%"></div><div class="on-hover"></div></a></aside></li>');
    $('#appended').append('<li class="refresh"><aside class="just-text"><div style="color: #000000; "><div class="textContainer"><text><div id="subHeading" style="color:black;height:1.2em!important;font-size:1.4em!important">'+data.posts[count].date+'</div><div id="subHeading2"><a href="<?= get_permalink();?>">'+data.posts[count].title+'</a></div></text></div></div><div class="on-hover"></div></a></aside></li>');
    count++;
})
.done(function( json ) {
       //$('#loading').hide();
  $(window).resize();
});

   });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Clicking the button throws:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'attachments' of undefined
```

I think your count is causing problems. Instead of using count try this:

```
$.getJSON('http://'+url2+'/?json=get_category_posts&slug=blog',function(data) {
$.each(data, function(i, post){
    $('#appended').append('... post.attachments[0].url ...
    $('#appended').append('... post.date ...
})
```

$.each will just go through each post instead using the index